# JavaScript loop slow (> two minutes) for unpacking array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some JSON data coming from a query received via XHR by my JavaScript. This is the structure of my received data:

```
[{
  "date": "17 February 1806",
  "dinnerID": "h1806-02-17a",
  "note": "...",
  "diners": {
    "name": [
      [
        "Lord Gilbert Elliot-Murray-Kynynmound"
      ],
      [
        "Humble Mr  Elliot"
      ],
      [
        "Mr  Allen"
      ],
      [
        "Lady  Holland"
      ],
      [
        "Lord  Holland"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
[etc...]
]
```

Iterating over my results is fine with a few results, say up to 200/300. If I have a query with more results though (it can get up to around 1000), the browser is unresponsive for more than two minutes after the XHR response has been received. You can see the the logged entries scrolling 'slowly' one by one in the console. Is this a structural limit, or is there something I can do?

```
// for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){ // These three variants
// for (let [i, val] of Object.entries(result)) { // don't make n appreciable difference
for (var dinner of result) { // to the time the loops takes to complete.
document.getElementById("resultSearch").innerHTML += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-' + result.dinnerID + '">' + result.date + '</button>'
console.log(dinner)
}
```

**Edit**

Putting the html populating outside the loop makes a big different.

Now, I'm also building a modal for each result. Unfortunately I seem not be able to append it correctly. I get a series of instead `[object HTMLDivElement]` of the modal itself. My code:

```
let links = ''
let modals = ''

for (var dinner of result) {
let modal = ['<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">',
  '<div class="modal-content">',
   [etc..]
  '</div>',
'</div>'].join('');
let divModal = document.createElement('div');
divModal.setAttribute(...)
...
divModal.innerHTML = modal;

modals += divModal

let button = document.createElement('button')
button.setAttribute(...)
...
button.innerHTML = dinner.date
links += button

}

document.getElementById("resultSearch").innerHTML += modals
document.getElementById("resultSearch").innerHTML += links
```

Shall I use `appendChild` also in the last two instruction? I get `Argument 1 is not an object` in that case.

**edit 2 and working code**

I've solved by putting the `appendChild` code inside the loop:

```
let fragmentLinks = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragmentLinks.appendChild(button);
targetLinks.append(fragmentLinks)
```

Although I'm calling `appendChild` at each iteration this takes less than a second versus the initial > minutes. So, I suppose, `fragment` *does* make things faster.

Comment: your performance problems are two fold, first logging each entry to the console will slow everything down so I wouldn't do that. More importantly adding elements to the DOM one by one is where you will really suffer on performance. Have a look at [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) which let's you build a complex structure without adding it to the DOM at each step. You can then add the completely built item to the DOM once you have built it and that will be magnitudes faster.

Comment: Thank you, I added the console.log just for testing after I noticed the performances issues of course, I'll take it out, thank you for pointing that out though. I didn't know about the documentFragment, I'm going to take a look. If you want to write a more articulate answer and it works for me then I'll accept it.

Comment: Another thing that might speed up your process is not querying the element in each iteration. Query it once outside the loop and use it like so ```const resultSearchElem = document.getElementById("resultSearch")```. Then use ```resultSearchElem.innerHTML += ...``` inside your loop.

Comment: I will let someone else steal the glory as I am not working at PC so it is hard to put code samples together etc. (but if noone answers I will put an answer and code example down for you later). One final point to be aware of is that `.innerHTML +=` is not the best idea in most scenarios as it will destroy event handlers you have set up. Instead use [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) if you are adding anything other than a string such as a `<button>`, `<a>` and build the element in JS with `.createElement` etc.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamRitchie, I've updated my question because I've some issue appending modals, even using `.createElement`.

Comment: If you write an answer when you can then I'll accept it, since you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GrahamRitchie I've solved by putting the appendChild code inside the loop.

```
let fragmentLinks = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragmentLinks.appendChild(button);
targetLinks.append(fragmentLinks)
```

Although I'm calling appendChild at each iteration this takes less than a second versus the initial > minutes. So, I suppose, fragment does make things faster.

Answer (score 1):

DocumentFragment is not faster then innerHTML, use `.innerHTML` outside the loop.

```
var htmlString = ''; 

for (var dinner of result) {
  htmlString += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-' + result.dinnerID + '">' + result.date + '</button>'
}

document.getElementById("resultSearch").innerHTML += htmlString;
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems very promising. One problem I'm having is: I'm also creating a modal for each result: `divModal.innerHTML = modal; modals += divModal` inside the loop and then `document.getElementById("resultSearch").innerHTML += modals` outside of it. It works with the links, it doesn't with modals. It outputs a series of `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

Comment: "document fragment is not faster than innerHTML" - have you ever tested it? https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/innerhtml/original.html I find it is way quicker nowadays but I could have missed something? I always thought this was only old school browsers as when I test the examples on that page it is 500 times faster in Chrome and FireFox to use a documentFragment, but the example may be flawed because of cloning a node?

Comment: I agree with @GrahamRitchie, it's extremely faster (see my updated question).

Comment: [check this](https://plnkr.co/edit/dIAIY7YOg60aF61X?preview) in my PC innerHTML took 2-3s while documentfragment 3-4s and innerHTML use less code. @HBMCS maybe you can try with `....innerHTML += modals.outerHTML`

Comment: I mean milliseconds not second